# Create IBOutlets from embedded UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

in my XCode Project I have a standard view with an `UIView` sitting in it.
Within that `UIView`, I embed a `TableView` with static cells.

Now I am trying to get some `IBOutlets` from the embedded `TableView cells` into my main (parent) `UIViewController`, which is apparently not working :(

I am new to all this iOS development thing and don't really understand what I am doing :D

Could anybody push me into the right direction? What am I missing?

Cheers folks

Chris

Comment: Is your table view a dynamic table view with prototype cells? If that is the case, adding outlets is likely to not work.

Comment: you need to add class for that custom cell or using tag property you can get that cell's view .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create IBOutlet inside your UIViewcontroller for the static tableview cells. You have to create a class which is subclass of UITableViewCell. Then try connecting the outlet inside the Custom class for UITableviewCell.

Comment: Thank you so much @Manoj - that did it! Have a great day. You just saved mine :D